# cakephp webservice

Tags: php, cakephp, soap, web-services, wsdl

I have problem in creating web-service using cakephp .
this what i do to create this web-service .
I use NuSOAP - Web Services Toolkit for PHP for this.
I create a controller called WsController  and import the library on it.

```
class WsController extends AppController{

var $uses = array();

function info()  {
    $this->layout= null;
    $ns="http://www.techvoicellc.com/Tutorials//"; 
    $server = new soap_server(); 


    $server->configureWSDL('mostafa',$ns); 
    $server->wsdl->schemaTargetNamespace=$ns; 
    $server->wsdl->addComplexType('ArrayOfstring','complexType', 
    'array','','SOAP-ENC:Array',array()
    ,array(array('ref'=>'SOAP-ENC:arrayType','wsdl:arrayType'=>'string[]')), 
    'xsd:string'); 


    $server->register('sum', 
    array('x' => 'xsd:integer','y' => 'xsd:integer'),        
    array('z' => 'xsd:integer'),   
    $ns,                                           
    "$ns#sum",                               
    'rpc',                                        
    'encoded',                                    
    'documentation'     // documentation 
    );  

    $server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA); 
}

 function sum($x,$y){ 
    $z=$x+$y;
    return new soapval('return','xsd:integer',$z);
 } 

}
```

and i create the clint in controller action like this

```
function index() {
   $wsdl = 'http://localhost/asd/ws/info?wsdl';
   $client = new nusoap_client ( $wsdl, true );

   $this->client = new nusoap_client($wsdl, true);
   $param1 = array ('x' => 2, 'y' => 1 );
   $a = $client->call ( 'sum', $param1 );
    echo $a;
 }
```

it don't do any thins although that i create this in non cake project and its work very well

hope some one tell me what is the best practise to create web-service in cake php

Comment: wow to much code, pls format your code ;-)

Comment: unfortunately i cant edit your question, i would edit and format your question so that it is more readable

Comment: Why are you `try` and `catching` an `echo` and `set()` statement? Neither of those will ever throw an exception.

Answer (score 2):

This is quite **Easy to develop web services in CakePHP**. I have done it several times. Check the below steps.

```
class MyWebServicesController  extends AppController {
    var $name = 'MyWebServices';
    var $layout = "ajax";

    function index() {
        $server = new SoapServer(null);
        $server->setObject($this);
        $server->handle();
        exit(0);
    }
    public function addNumbers($a,$b) {
        return $a+$b
    }
}
```

Now your web service is hosted at `http://webroot/MyWebServices`
Now you can call addNumbers like below.

```
$client = new SoapClient(null, array('location' => "http://webroot/MyWebServices");
$sum = $client->addNumbers(1+2);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is best to create restful web service. CakePHP has everything built in for REST. All you have to do is enable it and create json/xml views.

Here is a link with your starting point: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/rest.html

Is there a reason you want SOAP web service?

1. It will be so much harder to create and test SOAP web service
2. SOAP will require external libraries
3. It will be harder for users to use the SOAP web service